# WordPress exact search query

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I need to search for the exact title. but my code sometime fetch similar title which is like

`I love him,
I love,
I love my country,`

I need only search the second title "**I love**". How can I achieve this?

```
 $title= "I love";
    global $post;
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'course',
        "s" => $title,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'meta_key' => 'vibe_product',
        'meta_value' => ' ',
        'meta_compare' => '!=',
    );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the code below in your functions.php

```
add_filter( 'posts_where', 'custom_posts_where', 10, 2 );
function custom_posts_where( $where, &$wp_query )
{
    global $wpdb;
    if ( $specific_title = $wp_query->get( 'specific_title' ) ) {
        $where .= ' AND ' . $wpdb->posts . '.post_title = \'' . esc_sql( $wpdb->esc_like( $specific_title ) ) . '\'';
    }
    return $where;
}
```

and then use the get_posts or wp query function like this:

```
$title= "I love";
global $post;
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'course',
    "specific_title" => $title,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_key' => 'vibe_product',
    'meta_value' => ' ',
    'meta_compare' => '!=',
);
```